# ld would not link the static library because of it consider the library is not needed, but I need this library

Tags: c, linker, dpdk

This happens when I am using dpdk library.

DPDK library is using `__attribute__((constructor))` trick to register the module before `main()`.

Such as the virtio driver module, it declares an init function to register itself.

```
RTE_INIT(rte_virtio_pmd_init)
```

`RTE_INIT` uses constructor extension to make sure `rte_virtio_pmd_init` is called before `main()`

```
#define RTE_INIT(func) \
static void __attribute__((constructor, used)) func(void)
```

But nobody calls `rte_virtio_pmd_init()` or any other function in virtio module in my program, so linker will not link virtio module.

I tried different ways to resolve this issue, but all failed.

Here is what I tried:

1. use `--no-as-needed linker` flag, doesn't work

   `x86_64-poky-linux-gcc -m64 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse --sysroot=/home/hliu/atomos/build-temp/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/unittest/0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--no-as-needed -o l2_ut_dpdk l2_ut_dpdk.c -Wall -Werror -g -ldpdk -ldl -lpthread`
2. Specify all the libraries explicitly in the compile command, also failed

   `x86_64-poky-linux-gcc -m64 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse --sysroot=/home/hliu/atomos/build-temp/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/unittest/0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--no-as-needed -o l2_ut_dpdk l2_ut_dpdk.c -Wall -Werror -g -lrte_mempool_stack -lrte_pmd_i40e -lrte_pmd_ark -lrte_ethdev -lrte_pmd_null -lrte_pmd_null_crypto -lrte_lpm -lrte_pmd_ena -lrte_kvargs -lrte_cmdline -lrte_pmd_tap -lrte_pmd_sw_event -lrte_latencystats -lrte_bitratestats -lrte_efd -lrte_sched -lrte_pmd_kni -lrte_pmd_qede -lrte_hash -lrte_pmd_enic -lrte_pdump -lrte_pmd_lio -lrte_acl -lrte_pmd_af_packet -lrte_eventdev -lrte_port -lrte_ip_frag -lrte_pmd_bond -lrte_pmd_sfc_efx -lrte_pmd_e1000 -lrte_mbuf -lrte_pmd_virtio -lrte_metrics -lrte_cryptodev -lrte_reorder -lrte_pmd_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_distributor -lrte_vhost -lrte_pmd_bnxt -lrte_timer -lrte_pmd_avp -lrte_pmd_crypto_scheduler -lrte_pmd_thunderx_nicvf -lrte_pmd_skeleton_event -lrte_pmd_nfp -lrte_jobstats -lrte_net -lrte_mempool -lrte_pmd_ixgbe -lrte_mempool_ring -lrte_pipeline -lrte_pmd_octeontx_ssovf -lrte_pmd_vhost -lrte_meter -lrte_pmd_cxgbe -lrte_kni -lrte_pmd_vmxnet3_uio -lrte_ring -lrte_pmd_fm10k -lrte_table -lrte_cfgfile -lpthread -ldl`

I know the linker tool is very smart. But now the problem is it is too smart to make work done.

Is there any good approach to disable this smart feature and make my program be linked with the library?

Comment: Here is the command I used at last, it works:
             ${CC} -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -o l2_ut_dpdk    l2_ut_dpdk.c    -Wall -Werror -g -Wl,--whole-archive -ldpdk -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl -lpthread -lm